# Creating a form that lets a user create an unspecified number of database rows in JavaFX

Tags: java

I want to create a form that lets a user create multiple database rows. The number of rows will be unknown at compile time, so the user should be able to click a button to add a new set of controls to the form.  I have no idea where to start with this in java.  in PHP, I could do the following:

```
<input type="text" name="people[0][first_name]">
<input type="text" name="people[0][last_name]">
<input type="text" name="people[0][date_of_birth]">
```

And the post array of $_POST['people'] would look something like this:

```
People => array(
    0 => array(
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
        'date_of_birth' => '01/01/1970'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'first_name' => 'Salley',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'date_of_birth' => '05/12/1981'
    )
)
```

And I could loop through the array with

```
<?php foreach($_POST['people'] as $id => $person){ echo $person['first_name']; } ?>
```

How can I do something like this in JavaFX? I'm not even sure how to create the controls so I can iterate over them.

```
@FXML private TextField firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth;
@FXML private GridPane personPane;
@FXML private Button addPerson;

@Override
public void initialize(){
        addPerson.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                personPane.getRows().add(???);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I hope you mixed up compile-time and runtime

Comment: Yes i did mix them up.